# How to effectively do independent processes to the AppKit?

Tags: objective-c

I have been told, "AppKit controls don't take kindly to being updated from threads other than the main thread."

I have 2 processes:

```
- update variables in the heap periodically
- display values from the heap to the display
```

I did do:

```
NSThread *thread_Client = [[NSThread alloc] initWithTarget:self selector:@selector(myTcpClient) object:nil];
NSThread *thread_Display = [[NSThread alloc] initWithTarget:self selector:@selector(displayData) object:nil];
```

but after awhile it blanks out or locks up.

What is a better approach?

thx

Comment: Right now your app is spinning in the while loop on your background thread to update the UI. Even if you could write to the control, you'd be wasting tons of cycles. Instead, try adding a timer that gets called at a more reasonable refresh rate, like every half second. Have the timer attached to the main thread and do your UI update in its callback method.

Comment: I thought NSTimer is just another thread?  I was going to add Sleep(100) to it to see if that helps.

Comment: NSTimer is *not* "just another thread". Adding Sleep(100) without really understanding what you're doing isn't the way to go either. Jason's suggestion is sound. I'd suggest reading up on NSTimer to gain an understand how it actually works, then go from there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm a bit unclear about what you're trying to do. It sounds like you are trying to perform a cyclical operation in a background thread and (at the end of each cycle) use the results to update the UI. Other postings suggest using an NSTimer in the main thread (which is the *only* thread that you should use for updating the UI). You would have the timer fire every so often (repeatedly); in the callback that is invoked when it fires, you would copy whatever data/info from the object(s) being updated by the background thread into appropriate UI views and then invoke setNeedsDisplay to cause updating of the UI. An issue is the consistency of the info you are using: if the background thread continues to update object(s), you could copy a mix of old and new info into the UI. Perhaps you need a 'delivery' object that the background fills in and then passes to the UI updater; such an object would contain a consistent set of info as yielded at the end of the background cycle.

In any case you do not want to be sleeping in the main thread. All it does is slow down the UI response.

Comment: I was going to add Sleep to the a NSThread within a "while loop" to slow it down.

Comment: Perhaps the nature of the background thread can be used to provide a 'built-in' delay? E.g,. does it need to wait on anything? If it's truly just repeating the same computation, then a sleep is a reasonable way to delay the background thread between each computation cycle.